# Dual-Channel Recording Using Twilio?

Tags: twilio

I have been trying to record 2 channels using Twilio by setting up a conference call. This is what I have implemented:

```
<Response>
  <Say>Your call is being recorded</Say> 
    <Dial record="record-from-answer-dual" timeLimit="330" trim="trim-silence">
      <Conference waitUrl="">
        Conference Room
      </Conference>
    </Dial>
    </Response>
```

How it works is that I will call the twilio number first. then add another number to the call so its 3 way, with the twilio number being silence. I found I am not getting 2 separate channel between the 2 speaker. Instead, I think Twilio is using itself as one of the channel, and the original caller as the other. Is there a way to configure so that we can get triple channel to include or a way to set it so it doesn't consider itself as a channel?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you use `record-from-answer-dual` with a `<Conference>` [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#record) says:

> If a dual-channel recording option is used for a `<Dial>` with a nested `<Conference>`, the resulting recording file will have two channels. The parent leg (inbound caller) is represented in the first channel. The second channel includes the audio coming downstream from the conference.

There is not currently a way to make a triple channel recording.

Comment: Is there a way around this? Because if you use the record function separately, you can only record mono channel.

Comment: I guess you're trying to get a recording for each person on the conference? Currently that's not possible.

Comment: Perhaps, you can switch the order up of which phone you are recording? Right now, there's no value in recording from the Twilio number since its just silence all the way.

Comment: Huh, that's odd. The two channels should be the person that called in and the rest of the conference. Also, it occurs to me that if you did that for all the users that called into the conference you would get recordings for each of them and multiple recordings of "the rest of the conference". If you are finding one leg is just completely silent, then something may be going wrong and I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide them some call SIDs so they can check it out too.

Comment: Sent them a ticket. Hopefully they can figure it out. Thanks!